# Remove the underline for hyperlinks in the edit profile - preview section

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, hyperlinks

Underline for hyperlinks are displaying in the **Edit Profile** - **About me** *preview* section. But where as the actual block is displaying in the profile page, there the underline are not displayed for the hyperlinks.

So for the uniformity, please remove the underline for hyperlinks in the edit profile - preview section.

Screenshots for reference:

**Edit Profile & Settings -> Edit Profile -> About me -> Preview**

> [image: Edit Profile & Settings]

In the [**Profile** page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/312043/arulkumar)

> [image: Profile page]